# Outputting information without explicitly calling toString() in java

Tags: java, printing, tostring, implicit

For step 6 in the println i know how to call the toString explicitly but how do i output student information from the current student in the array WITHOUT calling toString() explicitly or using any accessor methods?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Students
{
  private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Student[] students;

    students = getStudents();
    printStudents(students);
  }

  private static Student[] getStudents()
  {
    Student[] temp;
    int       how_many;

    System.out.print("How many students? ");
    how_many = input.nextInt();
    purgeInputBuffer();
    temp =  new Student[input.nextInt()];  // Step 1 ???
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
    {
      getStudent();
      temp[i] = getStudent();     // Step 2
    }
    return temp;    // Step 3
  }

  private static Student getStudent()
  {
    String name,
           address,
           major;
    double gpa;

    System.out.print("Enter name: ");
    name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter address: ");
    address = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter major: ");
    major = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter GPA: ");
    gpa = input.nextDouble();
    purgeInputBuffer();

    return new Student(name, address, major, gpa);     // Step 4
  }

  private static void printStudents(Student[] s)
  {
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)    // Step 5
    {
      System.out.println(______);     // Step 6
    }
  }

  private static void purgeInputBuffer()
  {
    // ----------------------------------------------------
    // Purge input buffer by reading and ignoring remaining
    // characters in input buffer including the newline
    // ----------------------------------------------------
    input.nextLine();
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean you do not want to implement the toString() method for Student class?

Comment: i am confused on my instructions to start with, it is an assignment, i can use toString, just implicitly not explicitly

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare your variables `name, address, major, gpa` as member variables.
2. Override the `toString()` method for this class.

   ```
   public String toString() {
       return "Name: " + name + "\n" + "Address: " + .... //whatever you want to print.
   }
   ```
3. Whenever you need to print details of a student, pass it to the `println` method:

   ```
   System.out.println(obj); //where obj is a Student object.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

- In your `Stundent` class override the `toString()` method as, for example,:

  ```
  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return "Stundent [ Name: " + name + ", Address: " + address + ", Major: " + major + ", GPA: " + gpa + " ]";
  }
  ```
- And modify your `printStudents()` method as follows (your Step 6):

  ```
  private static void printStudents(final Student[] s) {
      System.out.println();
      for (final Student student : s) {
          System.out.println(student);
      }
  }
  ```
- Then your output should look like:

> Stundent [ Name: Name1, Address: Addr1, Major: Major1, GPA: 3.0 ] 
>   Stundent [ Name: Name2, Address: Addr2, Major: Major2, GPA: 3.5 ]

Now you see the `toString()` method will be invoked implicitly.